# «Не дороже денег». Как понимать?

Tags: фразеология, смысл, разговорная-речь

Эта уклончивая реплика на вопрос о цене, она от интереса в продолжении разговора или нежелания?

*Дорого обошлась вам радость преобретения домика? — Да не дороже денег...*

Comment: Не ценнее денег...

Comment: Уточнить надо, и это будет правильно. Спасибо, oleedd!

Comment: В этом примере как бы прикол. Говорят, что просто деньгами обошлось. Пользуются тем, что "дорого" можно по-разному понимать, в глобальном смысле не сколько денег, а чем обошлось.